# Android Titanium Twitter Integration

Tags: android, twitter, titanium

Suggest some working examples for android titanium `Twitter` integration.

I already  tried some sample like `Birdhouse`, Social java script file but with that i didn't get the required output.

i just want to post a text through my titanium android app into twitter. May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use social_plus.js it works for both android and iOS

https://github.com/aaronksaunders/test_social

Thanks

Comment: It is showing an error like TiExceptionHandler: (main) [62,4102] - Message: Uncaught TypeError: Object function Controller() Thanks

Comment: have u add the consumer key and secret in app?

Comment: yes i add them, i am testing it under android emulator running with 4.4 version OS  Thanks

Comment: Make sure you don't use a broken Titanium SDK version. I got errors with 3.3.0GA and 3.2.3.GA. Use one of the latest ones from http://builds.appcelerator.com.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

**My Problem Get Solved by the Below Code**

```
  var social = require('alloy/social').create({
        consumerSecret: 'consumer-secret',
        consumerKey: 'consumer-key'
    });

    // If not authorized, get authorization from the user
    if(!social.isAuthorized()) { 
        social.authorize();
    }

    // Post a message
    // Setup both callbacks for confirmation
    social.share({
        message: "Salut, Monde!",
        success: function(e) {alert('Success!')},
        error: function(e) {alert('Error!')}
    }); 

    // Deauthorize the application


    social.deauthorize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a intent share menu ? It allows users to send content on all installed 
apps that are able to share content. (email, sms, hangout, facebook...and twitter)

```
var createShareMenu = function(){

        var subject = 'My subject';
        var text = 'My text';

        var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
            action: Ti.Android.ACTION_SEND,
            type: "text/plain",
        });
        intent.putExtra(Ti.Android.EXTRA_TEXT,text);
        intent.putExtra(Ti.Android.EXTRA_SUBJECT,subject);

        var share = Ti.Android.createIntentChooser(intent,'Share');

        return share;
    };
```

and to show the share apps menu :

```
shareButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var share = createShareMenu();
    var activity = win.getActivity();
    activity.startActivity(share);
});
```